# html2text wants a bytes like object but is rejecting something of class bytes

Tags: python, email, html-parsing

I am trying to parse some emails using python and I am hitting a wall with html2text. The project is to take a bunch of emails that are responses to a form and get that into a workable csv format. You can invasion the body of the mail being akin to

```
name: <name>
email: <email address>
grade level: <grade level>
interests: <interests>
(etc)
```

I need get the body of the email and parse it from raw HTML to text so that I can work through it for questions and their corresponding answers. This is my code so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
""" Access email and get contents to csv """
import datetime, os, glob
import email, html2text, imaplib

EMAIL_UN = '<email address>'
EMAIL_PW = '<app token>'
MENTOR = 'Form Submission - Mentor Application'
MENTEE = 'Form Submission - Mentee Application'

cwd = os.getcwd()

sentSince = "SENTSINCE 01-Oct-2021"


def download_emails(SUBJECT):
    un = EMAIL_UN
    pw = EMAIL_PW
    url = 'imap.gmail.com'
    folder = "\"" + "Mentoring Program" + "\""
    complexSearch = sentSince + " Subject " + "\"" + SUBJECT + "\""
    detach_dir = cwd # directory where to save output (default: current)

    # connecting to the gmail imap server
    m = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(url,993)
    m.login(un,pw)
    m.select(folder)

    # # This allows us to cycle through the folders and labels in Gmail to find what we need
    # for items in m.list('/'):
    #     for item in items:
    #         print(item)
    
    resp, items = m.search(None, complexSearch)
    # you could filter using the IMAP rules here (check http://www.example-code.com/csharp/imap-search-critera.asp)
    
    items = items[0].split() # getting the mails id
    print("Items: \n{}".format(items))
    results = [] # This will be a list of dicts, to breakdown each email
    for emailid in items:
        resp, data = m.fetch(emailid, "(RFC822)") # fetching the mail, "`(RFC822)`" means "get the whole stuff", but you can ask for headers only, etc
        if resp != 'OK':
            raise Exception("Error reading email: {}".format(data))
        message = email.message_from_string(str(data[0][1])) # parsing the mail content to get a mail object
        # Next parse the mail object to get a dictionary with important data, text = body of email
        res = {
            'From' : email.utils.parseaddr(message['From'])[1],
            'From name' : email.utils.parseaddr(message['From'])[0],
            'Time' : message['Date'],
            'To' : message['To'],
            'Text' : '',
            'File' : None 
        }
        # message.walk is a generator that allows us to walk through the parts of the email
        for part in message.walk():
            if part.get_content_maintype() == 'multipart':
                continue
            if part.get_content_maintype() == 'text':
                # reading as HTML (not plain text)
                _html = part.get_payload(decode = True)
                print(type(_html)) # checking the type to make sure it's bytes
                res['Text'] = html2text.html2text(_html)
        results.append(res)
    print(results)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    download = input("Do you want to search for Mentor or Mentee forms? (enter: Mentor / Mentee) \n")
    if download.upper() == 'MENTOR':
        download_emails(MENTOR)
    elif download.upper() == 'MENTEE':
        download_emails(MENTEE)
    else:
        print('Usage: ./download_emails.py @ prompt enter Mentor or Mentee:')
```

The issue I am running into is that html2text is complaining about needing a bytes like object, but the class of _email is bytes.... what am I messing up here?? You can see the result of print(type(_html)) right before the error.

The error:

```
<class 'bytes'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Email_ScriptV0.0.1.py", line 97, in <module>
    download_emails(MENTOR)
  File "Email_ScriptV0.0.1.py", line 61, in download_emails
    res['Text'] = html2text.html2text(_html)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/html2text/__init__.py", line 947, in html2text
    return h.handle(html)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/html2text/__init__.py", line 142, in handle
    self.feed(data)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/html2text/__init__.py", line 138, in feed
    data = data.replace("</' + 'script>", "</ignore>")
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

Thanks for any and all help!

Comment: I think your problem is the opposite. html2text is trying to replace using a string, but you handed in a `bytes` object. The bytes object you passed is complaining that html2text thinks its a str.

Comment: Thanks, tried it with res['Text'] = html2text.html2text(str(_html)) and it made progress but the result of that is for res['Text'] to only equal b' ' which is not making a lot of os sense as the message seems to have a single huge block of text that is all the headers and the body of the email rolled into one.